# Laravel actualizar o crear datos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, php5

Tengo un `command` de `laravel` que lee un archivo `csv` y llamará a una función que por cada elemento, mirará si el elemento existe (lo actualizará) y si no existe lo creará.

El `command` es este:

```
    public function handle()
{
    if (false === file_exists($this->argument('file'))) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('File not found');
    }

    $this->file = $this->argument('file');
    $this->comment('--- Start reading CSV file ---');

    $handle = fopen($this->file, "r");

    $outPutCsvLine = [];
    while ($csvLine = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) {
    $data = [
           'name' => $csvLine[0];
           'category_id' => $this->searchCategoryByName($csvLine[1])
    ];

        $this->createOrUpdateAliment($data);
    }


}
```

Ahora tengo dudas con la función que creará este elemento, de momento tengo este código:

```
    private function createOrUpdateAliment($data) {
    $aliment = App\Aliment::where('name',$name)->first();

if (null === $aliment) {
       $aliment->create($data);
}
    else {
       .... // actualizar
   }
}
```

Tengo duda como hacer el "`update`" de este objeto.

Gracias

Comment: Por qué no usar los métodos de Eloquent destinados a eso que buscas en tu último código? Lee sobre firstOrCreate https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Comment: usa el updateOrCreate de eloquent después de definir tu $data en el handle, prueba algo como esto: $updateOrCreate = App\Aliment::updateOrCreate(
    ['name' => $csvLine[0]],
    $data
); .. busca un modelo con el name dado.. si existe lo actualiza con lo que va en el segundo argumento, si no existe: lo crea.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar el método `updateOrCreate` de Eloquent:

```
public function handle()
{
    if (false === file_exists($this->argument('file'))) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('File not found');
    }

    $this->file = $this->argument('file');
    $this->comment('--- Start reading CSV file ---');

    $handle = fopen($this->file, "r");

    $outPutCsvLine = [];
    while ($csvLine = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) {
    $data = [
           'name' => $csvLine[0];
           'category_id' => $this->searchCategoryByName($csvLine[1])
    ];

    /**
     * usando updateOrCreate
     * si encuentra un modelo que coincida con 'name': lo actualiza
     * de lo contrario lo crea usando lo que pasamos en $data
     */
    $updateOrCreate = App\Aliment::updateOrCreate(
        ['name' => $csvLine[0]],
        $data
    );

    }

}
```

Link documentación oficial: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada, utiliza la sintaxis de Laravel y lo resuelve en una sola línea. +1

Answer (score 2):

Según los datos que nos enseñas, cualquiera de estas dos formas debería actualizarte el registro:

```
private function createOrUpdateAliment($data) {
    $aliment = App\Aliment::where('name',$name)->first();

    if (null === $aliment) {
       $aliment->create($data);
    }
    else {
       //$aliment->update($data);

       //$aliment->category_id = $data['category_id'];
       //$aliment->save();
   }
}
```